# Binary Search vs. Linear Search (data structures & algorithms)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, binary-search, linear-search

Trying to wrap my head around some basic and common algorithms..  my current understanding of the question is in **bold**.

( 1 )  Assuming we have a sorted array with *n* items: at most how many times will a binary search compare elements?

**I keep seeing ' 0(log(n)) ' pop up as a general answer for this type of question but I do not understand why.  Is there not a whole number that answers this question (i.e. 2 or 3?)**

( 2 )  Assuming we have an array with *n* items: at most how many times will a linear search compare elements?

**Again, same as above, but now ' 0(n) ' seems to be the general answer to this question.  Again, I do not really understand the power behind this answer and question why there is not some whole number answer?**

( 3 )  Can someone explain an example when a linear search would be better than a binary search?

**From the information I have gathered, it generally seems like a binary search is a better option, if possible, because it is of it's quickness.  I'm having trouble seeing when a linear search would be a better option.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding 1&2, an absolute number as an answer would've been possible if an absolute number was provided as the size of the input. since the question asks about an arbitrarily sized array (of length `n`) then answer is also given in these terms.
you can read more about [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for details, but basically `O(n)` & `O(log n)` mean `order of n` & `order of log(n)` respectively. i.e. if the input size is 100, for example, the number of compared elements using linear search will also be in the order of 100 while using a binary search would require comparing ~ log(100) elements.
as for 3, binary search requires the input to be sorted...

Answer (score 1):

The O notation is about limiting behaviour. So a binary search divides the list into two. Either you have found the item or you have half to search. Hence the limiting bevaviour of O(nlogn) - i,e at the leaf of the search tree.

Linear search just starts at the beginning. Of the worst can (the limit) is the element is at the end).

For (3) if the item is the first in the list you have hit the jackpot. So would be better in that case

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are dealing with O notation, so a "whole number" isn't possible. Answers are are always in `O(f(n))` format where `f(n)` is some function of `n`. If you aren't sure what Big O notation is all about, then starting from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation may help.

(1) With binary search on a sorted array, the search space is repeatedly reduced by half, until the item is located. If we think about an ideal binary search implementation where every operations takes constant time, in the worst case we will need to examine approximately `logn` items - which will take `O(logn)` time. As to the math behind `logn`: they aren't  terribly difficult but it's hard to type it out on an iPhone. Hint: Google is your friend.

(2) in a linear search of an unsorted array, we may have to examine every item in the array. Again, this is a simplification, but assuming that every operation in our algorithm takes constant time, we must look at least `n` times. Hence `O(n)`.

(3) What is the difference in the data you must search in (1) and (2)? Remember that sorting is, optimally, `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNVCJj642n4) provides a comprehensive explanation. I hope it will help you to understand the difference between binary search and liner search.

For question3:

- binary search requires, sorted sequence.
- for sequence 1,2,3,...,100. When you want to find element 1, linear search will be faster. It will just check the first element.